# undefined method `root' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, cpanel, phusion

My question is, why must I see this error?

> undefined method `root' for main:Object

I get this when I go to my site and see Phusion page of errors. Here is long outputs:

> Ruby on Rails application could not be started These are the possible
> causes: There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please
> check for such errors and fix them. A required library may not
> installed. Please install all libraries that this application
> requires. The application may not be properly configured. Please check
> whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any
> incorrect configurations, and restart this application. A service that
> the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret
> search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that
> service. Further information about the error may have been written to
> the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the
> problem. Error message: undefined method `root' for main:Object
> Exception class: NoMethodError Application root:
> /home/$user/rails_apps/junkie Backtrace:
>
> ## File    Line    Location 0  /home/$user/rails_apps/$app/config/routes.rb    34
>
> 1 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb    227 in
> `draw' 2  /home/$user/rails_apps/$app/config/routes.rb    1    3 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 173 in` load_without_new_constant_marking'
> 4 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 173 in
> `load' 5 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb    287 in` load_routes!'
> 6 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb    287 in
> `each' 7 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb    287 in` load_routes!'
> 8 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb    267 in
> `reload!' 9 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb 537 in` initialize_routing'
> 10    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb 188 in
> `process' 11    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb 113 in` send'
> 12    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb 113 in
> `run' 13  /home/$user/rails_apps/$app/config/environment.rb   9    14    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in` gem_original_require'
> 15    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in
> `require' 16    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 222 in` preload_application'
> 17    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 181 in `initialize_server' 18    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 572 in` report_app_init_status'
> 19    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 174 in `initialize_server' 20    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in` start_synchronously'
> 21    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in
> `start' 22    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb 149 in` start'
> 23    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 219 in
> `spawn_rails_application' 24    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in` lookup_or_add'
> 25    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 214 in
> `spawn_rails_application' 26    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in` synchronize'
> 27    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in
> `synchronize' 28    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 213 in` spawn_rails_application'
> 29    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 132 in
> `spawn_application' 30    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in` handle_spawn_application'
> 31    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in
> `__send__' 32    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in` server_main_loop'
> 33    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in
> `start_synchronously'
> 34    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99

Here specs are:

gem list --local rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (2.3.14)

ruby -v && gem -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
1.8.23

In my config/environment.rb I specify rails 2.3.14

Also, I am of using cPanel but not using cPanel account to view and handle this app.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the app wants you to define the root route in config/routes.rb (open config/routes.rb for details)

Comment: I have this:# You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html. root :to => "home#index" # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes" # Install the default routes as the lowest priority. # Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should # consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources. map.connect ':controller/:action/:id' map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format' end

Comment: yeah, if you read it, it is written that you should set `map.root`; probably you deleted/renamed public/index.html, which is used by rails to set the homepage of a new project, so the app now misses of an homepage; you should specify the homepage setting `map.root :controller => "my_controller"`. Said that, I must add that your config/routes.rb it is more similar to rails 3, than rails 2!

Comment: What should I do to make the config/routes.rb more like the rails 2?

Comment: Also, I change routes to what you say, now I see this:

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

Where does index.html.erb go now?

Comment: it is normal, that controller does not exist, you should implement it! I suggest you to follow a tutorial (like [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)), so you can understand better how the framework works

Comment: This sauce is awesome. I will look at now.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this helps here ... I had basically a fresh install.  I made a scaffold call with:

```
mirv@rorblog:~/workspace/workspace (master) $ rails g scaffold User userID:integer index  name:string email:string password:string lastLogin:datetime
```

Which was obviously wrong ... but how to undo it?  As I had mistakenly done the "rake db:migrate" afterwards figuring we could remove it with a simple command.  Wrong, but luckily after comparing my github I noticed there was a difference in the start of my routes.rb file.

```
resources :users
```

The ruby scaffold destroy command had left one little line in the routes.rb file which mucked up the whole thing.  Without diff comparing on github, I'd have never noticed.  Below is the original error in case people are googling it blindly like I was ...

```
`<top (required)>': undefined method `resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

warning: circular argument reference - now


mirv@rorblog:~/workspace/workspace (master) $ rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting
    /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `require'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:8:in `require'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:3:in `load'
            from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```